# batch works on Windows 7 on WinCE sucks

Tags: batch-file, windows-ce

I have written the following synchronization code batch to flush all data inside a master hard drive into a backup drive. Because of drives name can change I used a trick putting master.txt into source drive and backup.txt into backup drive. In this way I can easily find source and backup. Omn windows 7 it works pretty well but once inside WinCE the hell.

```
cls

::@echo off

PATH=\hard disk;\hard disk2;\hard disk3;\hard disk4;e:;f:;g:

for %%A in ("%path:;=";"%") do (

    if exist %%~A\master.txt (
        echo found %%~A\master.txt
        SET data=%%~A\Rilevamenti
    )   
    if exist %%~A\backup.txt (
        echo found %%~A\backup.txt
        SET backup=%%~A
    )   
)

echo source path is: %data%

:logfile
Time /T > Time.dat
SET /P ftime= < Time.dat

SET DirName=BackupFiles%date:~6%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%ftime:~0,2%%ftime:~3,2%

SET backup=%backup%\%DirName%

echo backup dir is: %backup%

pause

mkdir "%backup%"

echo 1 > LogSyncFile_src
echo 1 > LogSyncFile_dst

SET COPYCMD=/Y

for /R "%data%" %%F in (*.CSV) do (
    move %%F %backup%\%%~nxF
    echo %%~nxF  >> LogSyncFile_src
)

for /R "%backup%" %%F in (*.CSV) do (
    echo %%~nxF  >> LogSyncFile_dst
)

SET /P Build=<LogSyncFile_src
SET /P Synch=<LogSyncFile_dst

if %Build%==%Synch% (
    goto :delete
) else (
    goto :fail
)

:fail 
echo synchronization failed!
goto :exit

:lowmemory 
echo Insufficient memory to copy files or 
echo invalid drive or command-line syntax. 
goto :exit

:abort 
echo You pressed CTRL+C to end the copy operation. 
goto :exit

:delete 
echo synchronization completed!
goto :exit

:exit

pause
```

On WinCE for the first loop I get:

> for %%A in ("%path:;=";"%") do ( Cannot execute for.exe

Any help on what's going on? It is the second time I write the same batch in a different way to get working on WinCE as well but it seems I am missing something...

Comment: As per [Command Processor Commands (Windows CE 5.0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms907227.aspx), there is no `for` command.

Comment: Terrible! Thank you.